# ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 3 21]

Tags: python

There are a multiple threads already on this issue but none of the proposed solutions seem to be working for me.

Here is my code:

```
  count_vect = CountVectorizer()
  X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(s) 
  tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
  X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)
  tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer() 
  X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
  clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, target_train)
```

I get the following error when I run this code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "distance_sup1.py", line
>   447, in 
>       clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, target_train)   File "C:\Users\Akanksha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py",
>   line 527, in fit 
>       X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr')   File "C:\Users\Akanksha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 520, in check_X_y    check_consistent_length(X, y)   File
>   "C:\Users\Akanksha\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py",
>   line 176, in check_consistent_length
>       "%s" % str(uniques)) ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 3 21]

**My target_train is**: [1, 1, 0]
**X_train_tfidf is:**

```
(0, 5)---1.0    
(2, 2)---0.670546709445    
(2, 17)---0.741867313239    
(3, 12)---0.707106781187    
(3, 13)---0.707106781187     
(4, 9)---0.741867313239    
(4, 2)---0.670546709445     
(5, 8)---0.707106781187     
(5, 0)---0.707106781187     
(6, 10)---1.0     
(7, 7)---0.457600845725     
(7, 3)---0.457600845725     
(7, 16)---0.457600845725     
(7, 1)---0.457600845725     
(7, 5)---0.40299610912     
(9, 6)---0.351227138886     
(9, 4)---0.398817338825     
(9, 9)---0.702454277773     
(9, 2)---0.317461354673     
(9, 17)---0.351227138886     
(10, 15)---0.707106781187     
(10, 14)---0.707106781187      
(11, 11)---0.750463470011     
(11, 6)---0.660911930729
```

I have tried reshaping it and transforming X_train_tfidf, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated.